# Reading webpage's inspect element data using java

Tags: java, web-crawler

I have a requirement . I am reading file from a dynamic web page , and the values which i require from the webpage lies within

```html
<td>
```

, and this is visible when i inspect this element . So my question is , is it somehow possible to print the data contained in the inspect element using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this one , leaving this answer in case if anyone stuck into this in future.

To print whatever you see inside inspect element can be tracked down using **selenium**.

Here's the code which i used `

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.whatever.com");
Thread.sleep(1000);
List<WebElement> frameList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("frame"));
System.out.println(frameList.size());
driver.switchTo().frame(0);               
String temp=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/thead/tr/td/div[2]/table/thead/tr[2]/td[2]")).getText();
```

read [here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-tutorial-18/) for more .

Comment: Can this be used for getting information on games played on a webpage such as diep.io? I need to be able to get the basic information from this game for a bot I am trying to make

Answer (score 1):

Using [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/). Here is the [cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

```
ArrayList<String> downServers = new ArrayList<>();
Element table = doc.select("table").get(0);
Elements rows = table.select("tr");

for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
    Element row = rows.get(i);
    Elements cols = row.select("td");

    // Use cols.get(index) to get the data from td element
}
```